What connection string should I use to connect to SQLite database in a Visual Studio .NET Framework WinForms application?
I am having trouble connecting to my SQLite database and creating a dataset from it in Visual Studio 2022. I believe the issue is with the connection string. I have:

Installed the SQLite and SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension in Visual Studio.
Installed the following NuGet packages:

System.Data.SQLite
System.Data.SQLite.Core
System.Data.SQLite.EF6
System.Data.SQLite.Linq
Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework
SQLite, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
SQLitePCLRaw.core


After installing the extension I went to this window.
I'm now at the connection string popup. What to enter here for the connection string? It says:

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider, It may not be installed


Folder structure of my project.

What connection string should I use to connect to my AccountingApp.db SQLite database in a Visual Studio 2022 .NET Framework 4.8 WinForms application with RDLC reports?
